# Contents of string change when exiting loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, xor

I have a simple function, that checks if the strings given match a certain condition, then generate a 3rd string based on the 2 ones received as arguments. The 3rd string is fine but when I return it it suddenly turn into "`\n`".

```
string sReturn = "";
if (sText.size() != sPassword.size()) {
     //Checks to see if the texts match a condition
     return sReturn;
}
for (int foo = 0; foo < sText.size(); foo++) {
    sReturn = "";
    sReturn += (char)sText[foo] ^ (char)sPassword[foo];
}
return sReturn;
```

In the for `sReturn` is fine and has the right contents, but as soon as it exists the loop, the debugger suddenly tells me it's contents are "`\n`". What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: FYI:  Only the last iteration through your for-loop actually has any effect, since you empty `sReturn` every time the loop body begins.

Comment: You should make that an answer James

Comment: Show the function definition and where it is being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You don't have to initialize string
   with empty character array like:

   ```
   std::string sReturn = "";
   ```

   [Default constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_constructor) meant to do it
   for you and is much more efficient.
   Correct code:

   ```
   std::string sReturn;
   ```
2. Assigning an empty string to sReturn
   on each iteration in your loop is
   incorrect. Not to mention that to
   clear a string you have to call
   [std::string::clear ()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/clear/):

   ```
   sReturn = "";
   ```

   Correct code:

   ```
   sReturn.clear ();
   ```

   But this should be removed from the
   loop at all in your case.
3. There is not need to explicitly
   convert the result of operator []
   (size_t) into a character because it
   is a character:

   ```
   sReturn += (char)sText[foo] ^ (char)sPassword[foo];
   ```

   Correct code:

   ```
   sReturn += sText[foo] ^ sPassword[foo];
   ```
4. Using [post-increment](http://cplus.about.com/od/glossar1/g/postincdefn.htm) in for
   loop is not necessary. It makes an
   extra copy of the "foo" on every
   increment:

   ```
   for (int foo = 0; foo < sText.size(); foo++)
   ```

   This probably will be optimized by
   compiler but you have to get rid of
   this bad habit. Use
   [pre-increment](http://cplus.about.com/od/glossar1/g/preincdefn.htm) instead. Correct
   code:

   ```
   for (int foo = 0; foo < sText.size(); ++foo)
   ```
5. Calling std::string::size () on
   every iteration when string size
   does not change is not efficient:

   ```
   for (size_t foo = 0; foo < sText.size(); ++foo)
   ```

   Better code:

   ```
   for (size_t foo = 0, end_foo = sText.size(); foo < end_foo; ++foo)
   ```

   Note size_t type. You cannot store
   string size in 32-bit signed integer
   as it has not enough capacity to
   store large number. Correct type is
   size_t, which is returned by
   std::string::size () method.

Taking into account all above, the correct function should look something like this:

```
std::string
getMixedString (const std::string & text, const std::string & password)
{
    std::string result;
    if (text.length () != password.length ())
        return result;
    for (size_t pos = 0, npos = text.length (); pos < npos; ++pos)
        result += text[pos] ^ password[pos];
    return result;
}
```

But there is a problem if you want the final string to be human-readable. Using [eXclusive OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) (XOR) operator on two [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) characters might or might not give you human readable character or even an [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) character. So you may end up having resulting string that contains newlines, unreadable characters, some [garbage](http://blog.lib.umn.edu/stau0156/architecture/garbage%20can.jpg) whatsoever.

To solve this, you have to come up with some better algorithm to generate a string basing on two other strings. For example, you may use [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) hash of both strings or encode them in [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Only now I noticed that I had put the string clear within the loop, a mistake out of lack of attention. I also found lots of other little information in your answer that I wasn't aware of and could help improve my code. I do however still have one more question. Every time the loop executed in the debugger watch window the string got bigger and bigger (apparently ignoring the string clear) and finally turns into "\n".

Comment: What do you mean 'the string got bigger and bigger'

Comment: If you consider that he was outputting the string on every iteration (for debugging), then I think he means it was outputting one character at a time... For example, if you output the string "ABCDE" being *built* one character at a time, every time through the loop, you would expect "AABABCABCDABCDE". In this case it was only outputting one character (because that was all that was in the string) and was getting "ABCDE". Easy to miss error since it was the string you were "expecting"

Comment: Each time I ran the loop with the debugger the string received one more character. "A" then "AB" and so on ... "ABCDEF" and when the iteration finished and it reach the return line it became "\n". It seemed that while in the loop the string was being built fine (although it shouldn't) and the problem occured after exiting the loop. But that could be the debugger's fault.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you have `sReturn = ""` *inside* the loop. Shouldn't that be initialized before the loop?

In the given case `sReturn` will only ever have one character. In your case, I would assume the ^ operation is resulting in a \n character in the last iteration.

Answer (score 2):

You've already had the problem explained. I'll suggest a completely different way of doing things that I think eliminates most possibility of producing a similar mistake. First, I'd separate the "check if the texts match a condition" part from the "encode" part. Right now, you have one (fairly small) of code that seems to have two, mostly unrelated, responsibilities.

The encode part, I'd write something like this:

```
struct encode_byte { 
    char operator()(char a, char b) { 
        return a ^ b;
    }
};

std::transform(sText.begin(), sText.end(),
               sPassword.begin(), sPassword.end(),
               std::back_inserter(sResult),
               encode_byte());
```

Comment: I'm sort of a beginner in programming, especially C++ so could you please explain this code to me ? As far as I can see you are overloading an operator, but I'm lost.

Comment: I have done a bit of reading and I now understand how the transform function works (apply function to range) and that you've overloaded the '()' operator. Thanks for this idea.

Answer (score 2):

```
string sReturn;
if (sText.size() != sPassword.size()) {
        return sReturn;
}
for (size_t foo = 0, end_foo = sText.size(); foo < end_foo; ++foo) {
        sReturn += sText[foo] ^ sPassword[foo];
}
return sReturn;
```

I have rewrote it now using everyone's tips. I appologize for the mistake caused by the lack of attention -- clearing the string everytime I run through the loop. I hope it is OK now, please tell me if there is anything that is wrong with it. Thanks to everyone for their prompt answers.

Comment: PS: anyone mind telling me why the last character is always a backspace ? No matter what strings I use the always character is 10 (BS, backspace) in ASCII.